# Data-frame output not as expected in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Below is a program I wrote,

```
func <- function(id = 1:200)
{
dir_char <- as.character(directory) ### changing directory input to character
set_dir <- paste('C:/Users/Junk/Documents/',dir_char,sep="") ### setting working directory path
setwd(set_dir)  ### setting input directory as working directory
count <- 0
for (i in id)   ### going through the id values
{
    id_char <- as.character(i)   ### changing id value to character for setting the file name
    new_file <- data.frame(read.csv(paste(id_char,".csv",sep="")))
    mod_file <- data.frame(new_file[complete.cases(new_file),])
    count <- nrow(mod_file) 
    print(count)
    out_file <- data.frame(id = id, nobs = count)
}
return(out_file)}
```

Output to this function is as follows

```
[1] 1041
[1] 474
[1] 192 
[1] 148
[1] 96
   id nobs
1  2   96
2  4   96
3  8   96
4 10   96
5 12   96
```

Why is the data-frame `out_file` not storing the `count` values after each loop iteration, I was expecting the data-frame to store the `print(count)` values to the out_file. Where am I going wrong, please help me figure out the problem.

Comment: count is a inbuilt function of many different packages, try changing the name count to cnt.

Comment: `out_file <- data.frame(id = id, nobs = count)` is creating a data.frame in every loop. The last one is returned which got value as `96`

Comment: @MKR thats true but isn't it weird to have different id's but same nobs ? I am confused !

Comment: @anup Actually, `id` is array and value remains same but `count` is changing in each loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done a few things wrong. A part of the explanation is made my `MKR` in his answer. The loop is creating problem. Besides, I assume you want one `nobs` for one `id`. If so, try this::

```
  func <- function(id = 1:200)
    {
    dir_char <- as.character(directory) ### changing directory input to character
    set_dir <- paste('C:/Users/Junk/Documents/',dir_char,sep="") ### setting working directory path
    setwd(set_dir)  ### setting input directory as working directory
    cnt<- 0
    out_file <- data.frame(id = numeric(), nobs = numeric())
    for (i in id)   ### going through the id values
    {
        id_char <- as.character(i)   ### changing id value to character for setting the file name
        new_file <- data.frame(read.csv(paste(id_char,".csv",sep="")))
        mod_file <- data.frame(new_file[complete.cases(new_file),])
        cnt<- nrow(mod_file) 
        print(cnt)
        out_file <- rbind(out_file, data.frame(id = i, nobs = cnt))
    }
    # the last line is always returned.. no need to use return
    out_file
   }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if above solution will work. `rbind` will keep on adding multiple rows for all `id` in every loop.

Comment: sorry that should be `i` not `id` in the rbind. see again .. i have updated the answer @MKR

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the doubt. Here `id` is a vector and I've defined the `data.frame` inside the for loop, so only the last iteration value is returned. Is this (usage is rbind() function) the right approach in this type of senarios or there is some function or method exists? 
In other languages, when we write a loop variable to a file, it is automatically stored one after the other, that is what caused the confusion, defining the `data.frame` inside the loop was a mistake...

Comment: @user1844 I'm not sure which df did you mean by "defining the df inside the loop was mistake". From what you have coded, the loop performs iteration and everytime the `out_file` is replaced by `data.frame(id = id , nobs = count)`. That means, instead of adding or appending the new data to the df `out_file` it is replaced with every time the loop runs with a new value. And as you can see from your result, the `print(count)` has 96 as the last value. And this value is repeated to all the id's (which is a vector) and saved to a df. If you follow my example, it should work. ++

Comment: and there are other ways as well but I'm not sure about their usage right now. for eg merge could be another option but their usefulness depends upon you requirement. To me, `rbind` solves my problem. It should solve yours as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in line

```
`out_file <- data.frame(id = id, nobs = count)`
```

The `data.frame` is getting created in every loop. And the last one is returned. You can change the logic and create `data.frame` after `loop` ends.

One way to fix the problem can be (I have modified relevant section of function):

```
func <- function(id = 1:200)
{
dir_char <- as.character(directory) ### changing directory input to character
set_dir <- paste('C:/Users/Junk/Documents/',dir_char,sep="") ### setting working directory path
setwd(set_dir)  ### setting input directory as working directory

count <- numeric(length(id))
for (i in id)   ### going through the id values
{
    ### changing id value to character for setting the file name
    id_char <- as.character(i)   
    new_file <- data.frame(read.csv(paste(id_char,".csv",sep="")))
    mod_file <- data.frame(new_file[complete.cases(new_file),])
    count[i] <- nrow(mod_file) 
    print(count)

}
 out_file <- data.frame(id = id, nobs = count)
 return(out_file)
}
```